# Replace character before and after period - Regular expressio

Tags: regex

I'm trying to replace the character before and after a period.

My sentence has the following syntax:

```
('ΑΕ027428',,,1.2,3,14),
```

And i want to convert it to:

```
('ΑΕ027428',,,'1.2',3,14),
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: I think you can capture your expected part by `(\d+\.\d+)` and then replace it ;).

Comment: I try to edit an insert slq query in notepad++. @shA.t thanks for the hint...that did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to perform a search and replace in notepad++. Thanks to @shA.t i've come up to the solution which is:

```
Find what: (\d+\.\d+)
Replace with: \'$1\'
```

Answer (score 0):

the regular expression to catch just the list items containing a decimal number (which I assume is what you are looking for is:
`'(\d+)[.](\d+)'`
in order to use the captured groups you need to use their id:

Using Perl from command line this can be done in such manner:

```
$ perl -e "s/'(\d+)[.](\d+)'/$1.$2/g;" < your entire text
```

Using sed is basically the same:

```
$ sed -i 's/'(\d+)[.](\d+)'/$1.$2/g' < your entire text
```

basically what you do here is find all items in your text that are suitable to your pattern, and then break them apart to two "capture groups". Then you rebuild these captured elements to the form you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can use this:

```
s/(.\..)/'$1'/g
```

Capture the two characters on either side of a period and quote them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $string = "('AE027428',,,1.2,3,14),";

$string =~ s/(.\..)/'$1'/g;

print $string;
```

Output:

```
('AE027428',,,'1.2',3,14),
```